# Why are there execution plan differences between OFFSET ... FETCH and the old-style ROW_NUMBER scheme?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, optimization, offset-fetch

The new `OFFSET ... FETCH` model introduces with SQL Server 2012 offers simple and faster paging. **Why are there any differences at all considering that the two forms are semantically identical and very common?**

One would assume that the optimizer recognizes both and optimizes them (trivially) to the fullest.

Here is a very simple case where `OFFSET ... FETCH` is ~2x faster according to the cost estimate.

```
SELECT * INTO #objects FROM sys.objects

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) r
    FROM #objects
) x
WHERE r >= 30 AND r < (30 + 10)
    ORDER BY object_id

SELECT *
FROM #objects
ORDER BY object_id
OFFSET 30 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

[image: offset-fetch.png]

One can vary this test case by creating a CI on `object_id` or adding filters but it is impossible to remove all plan differences. `OFFSET ... FETCH` is always faster because it does less work at execution time.

Comment: Not very sure, so putting it as comment, but I guess its because you have the same order by condition for the row numbering and the final result set. Since in the 2nd condition, the optimizer knows this, it does not need to sort the results again. In the first case however, it need to make sure the results from the outer select are sorted as well as the row numbering in the inner result. Creating a proper index on #objects should solve the issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The examples in the question do not quite produce the same results (the `OFFSET` example has an off-by-one error).  The updated forms below fix that issue, remove the extra sort for the `ROW_NUMBER` case, and use variables to make the solution more general:

```
DECLARE 
    @PageSize bigint = 10,
    @PageNumber integer = 3;

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT TOP ((@PageNumber + 1) * @PageSize) 
        o.*,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY o.[object_id])
    FROM #objects AS o
    ORDER BY 
        o.[object_id]
)
SELECT
    x.name,
    x.[object_id],
    x.principal_id,
    x.[schema_id],
    x.parent_object_id,
    x.[type],
    x.type_desc,
    x.create_date,
    x.modify_date,
    x.is_ms_shipped,
    x.is_published,
    x.is_schema_published
FROM Numbered AS x
WHERE
    x.rn >= @PageNumber * @PageSize
    AND x.rn < ((@PageNumber + 1) * @PageSize)
ORDER BY
    x.[object_id];

SELECT
    o.name,
    o.[object_id],
    o.principal_id,
    o.[schema_id],
    o.parent_object_id,
    o.[type],
    o.type_desc,
    o.create_date,
    o.modify_date,
    o.is_ms_shipped,
    o.is_published,
    o.is_schema_published
FROM #objects AS o
ORDER BY 
    o.[object_id]
    OFFSET @PageNumber * @PageSize - 1 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` plan has an estimated cost of **0.0197935**:

[image: Row Number Plan]

The `OFFSET` plan has an estimated cost of **0.0196955**:

[image: Offset Plan]

That is a saving of **0.000098** estimated cost units (though the `OFFSET` plan would require extra operators if you want to return a row number for each row).  The `OFFSET` plan will still be slightly cheaper, generally speaking, but do remember that estimated costs are exactly that - real testing is still required.  The bulk of the cost in both plans is the cost of the full sort of the input set, so helpful indexes would benefit both solutions.

Where constant literal values are used (e.g. `OFFSET 30` in the original example) the optimizer can use a TopN Sort instead of a full sort followed by a Top.  When the rows needed from the TopN Sort is a constant literal and <= 100 (the sum of `OFFSET` and `FETCH`) the execution engine can use [a different sort algorithm](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/sorting-row-goals-and-the-top-100-problem.html) which can perform faster than generalized TopN sort.  All three cases have different performance characteristics overall.

As to why the optimizer does not automatically transform the `ROW_NUMBER` syntax pattern to use `OFFSET`, there are a number of reasons:

1. It's almost impossible to write a transform that would match all existing uses
2. Having some paging queries automatically transformed and not others could be confusing
3. The `OFFSET` plan is not guaranteed to be better in all cases

One example for the third point above occurs where the paging set is quite wide.  It can be much more efficient to [seek the keys needed](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/69892/) using a nonclustered index and manually lookup against the clustered index compared with scanning the index with `OFFSET` or `ROW_NUMBER`.  There are [additional issues to consider](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/70120/) if the paging application needs to know how many rows or pages there are in total.  There is another good discussion of the relative merits of the 'key seek' and 'offset' methods [here](https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/04/26/offset-without-offset.aspx).

Overall, it is probably better that people make an informed decision to change their paging queries to use `OFFSET`, if appropriate, after thorough testing.

Comment: So the reason for the transformation not being done in common cases is probably that it was too hard to find an acceptable engineering trade-off. You provided good reasons for why that might have been the case.; I must say that this is a good answer. Many insights and new thoughts. I'll leave the question open for a bit and and then choose the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

With a slight fiddling of your query I get an equal cost **estimate** (50/50) and equal IO stats:

```
; WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) r
    FROM #objects
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE r >= 30 AND r < 40
ORDER BY r

SELECT *
FROM #objects
ORDER BY object_id
OFFSET 30 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

This avoids the additional sort that appears in your version by sorting on `r` instead of `object_id`.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Now that I think about this I have seen the optimizer not understand the sorted nature of the ROW_NUMBER output before. It considers the set to be unordered by object_id. Or at least not sorted both by r and object_id.

Comment: @usr the ORDER BY that ROW_NUMBER() uses defines how it assigns the numbers. It does nothing to promise the output order - that's separate. It just so happens that it often coincides, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I understand that ROW_NUMBER does not order the output. But if ROW_NUMBER is ordered by the same columns as the output is, then the same order *is* guaranteed, right? So the query optimizer could make use of that fact. So two sort operations are *always* unneeded in this query.

Comment: @usr you've hit a common use case that the optimizer doesn't account for, but it is not the *only* use case. Consider cases where the order by inside ROW_NUMBER() is that column and something else. Or when the outer order by does secondary sorting on another column. Or when you want to order descending. Or by something else altogether. I like ordering by the expression `r` instead of the base column, if only because it matches what I would do in a non-nested query and ordering by an expression - I would use the alias assigned to the expression instead of repeating the expression.

Comment: @usr And to Paul's point, there are going to be cases where you can find gaps in functionality in the optimizer. If they're not going to be fixed, and you know a better way to write the query, use the better way. Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do x." Doctor: "Don't do x." :-)

Answer (score -3):

They modified the query optimizer to add this feature in.  Meaning they implemented mechanisms specifically to support the offset ... fetch command. In other words for the top query SQL Server has to do a lot more work.  Thus the difference in query plans.